# Remove age/country restrictions using graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to remove any country and/or age restrictions that are set on a Facebook Page using graph API. Does anyone know if this is possible? It is for apps but I don't see this specific option anywhere documenten for pages.

Comment: The API docs for the page object do not mention any possibility to do so, so I guess it's not possible right now.